# upgrade cassandra 1.1.2 -> 1.1.12 without LeveledCompactionStrategy

Tags: cassandra

I use cassandra 1.1.2 and I would like to upgrade it to 1.1.12. My sstables do not have the LeveledCompactionStrategy specified. Following http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/install/upgrading#sstable-scrub it is not clear to me if I have to do the scrub or if a can proceed with the points 6 and 7 of http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/install/upgrading#completing-upgrade . Could you clarify the procedure?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards,
Silvio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No special actions are needed; drop the new jar in and restart.